# Luggage policy for "Trans-Island Limousine" buses from HK to mainland China

Tags: luggage, china, buses, hong-kong

I'm planning on taking one of [these routes](http://www.trans-island.com.hk/en/servicelist.php?nid=2) with Trans-Island Limousine from HK to mainland China.  In [this PDF](http://www.trans-island.com.hk/en/pdf/TIL_Cross%20Boundary%20Bus%20Rules.pdf), it seems that item 5 specifies that passengers are limited to one luggage of size 25"x16"x9" and under 22 pounds, and another piece of size 15"x10"x6".

This seems ridiculously limiting compared to buses in the US.  I'm wondering if anybody has had experience bringing large luggage aboard these buses.  I plan on having quite a bit of luggage (one check-in sized luggage, and one airplane overhead carry-on sized luggage).  Does anybody have experience with them? How strict are they about luggage?  Are the buses really small or unable to accommodate a lot of luggage?

Answer (score 1):

My friend and I just took a trip with Trans-Island Limousine with the following luggage:

- 2 backpacks
- 2 carry-on sized roller luggages
- 1 carry-on sized large duffel bag
- 1 check-in sized large roller luggage

All of the luggage except our backpacks were over 22 pounds, and the check-in sized luggage definitely violated all size constraints.

We brought the backpacks aboard the bus, and they let us store everything else underneath without extra payment.  There did not seem to be any mechanism for measurement of the weight since the bus just picks you up from a street near an MTR station in Hong Kong.  I assume length/width/height constraints would only be enforced by "eye tests" if they are enforced at all. The buses are rather large (similar to Greyhound bus sizes in the US), so there's quite a bit of luggage space.  Overhead space inside the bus is rather limited.  However, there were very few passengers on the bus -- the bus was more than half empty.  I'm not sure whether they would charge fees for excessive baggage if the bus is more full.